# Is it possible to receive most if not all items in TF2 from the drop system?

Tags: team-fortress-2

It seems mostly to me that the drop system is giving me the same items every single time. (Atleast 3 times in a row now, the Engineer's hand that places mini-sentries.)

Comment: Lucky. I've played the game for years and never gotten a mini sentry... I had to trade for one

Comment: I'm also on mobile so I can't invest in writing a fully fleshed out answer atm, but there are certain items that cannot be obtained by drops as listed on the TF2 Wiki: https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Item_drop_system#Non-dropping_items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have bad luck.

You can get most of the normal quality (unique) weapons/cosmetics and tools from the drop system.

The weapons you cannot get from the drop system are going to either have special qualities associated with them (such as strange) or are reskins of other weapons.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your title - no. You can obtain most weapons in TF2 through the drop system, but you can't get weapons in limited supply (such as the Golden Frying Pan). As for you getting the Gunslinger 3 times in a row, well, that's just bad luck.